# Merging PDF with itext at certain position

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm here to ask if someone knows if it is possible to do AddDocument with PdfCopy or PdfSmartCopy but that the document is placed not from the left bottom corner but from the center?

We are combining several pdf files but some can be a bit larger in width and height. When placed, those larger files will not be displayed entirely.

Hope someone can help or answer me. 
Thanks

Code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    var pdfDoc = new Document();
    var pdf = new PdfSmartCopy(pdfDoc, stream);
    pdfDoc.Open();

    foreach (var doc in docs)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes(doc.Path));
        pdf.AddDocument(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }

    pdfDoc.Close();
    pdf.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `AddDocument()` in `PdfCopy` and `PdfSmartCopy` respects the original dimensions of the original pages. Are you saying you want to change those dimension? E.g. are we talking about changing the `/CropBox` value?

Comment: Can you take a look at [chapter 5 of the iText 7 jumpstart tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document). Are you trying to do what is explained under the title "Changing the page size and orientation"?

Comment: So say we have two pdf files. 1 is A4 size (210 x 297mm) and the other is larger like 230 x 308mm. We do the `AddDocument()` for the first file and then the second. We see that the second file is partially displayed and the created PDF is A4-size

Comment: This shouldn't happen with `AddDocument` and `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy`. The behavior you describe is what happens when you use `Document`/`PdfWriter`/`PdfImportedPage`. Also: why aren't you using [iText 7 for C#](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/releases/tag/7.0.0) for your POC?

Comment: We are using the iTextSharp nuget package version 5.5.9

Comment: I'm a Java guy. It works correctly in Java. Let's hope @ChrisHaas can take a look. Nevertheless: you should post your code so that we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I just tested the [AddCover1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/adding-cover-page-existing-pdf#40-addcover1.java) example with iText 5.5.9. I combined [hero.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/hero.pdf) with [pages.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/pages.pdf). Different files sizes are involved and those different file sizes are respected in the final result. In short: the behavior you describe can not be reproduced. We can't fix problems we can't reproduce.

Comment: @JonathanRasquin Can you share a sample set of PDFs to reproduce the issue?